# Using Laravel's query builder or Eloquent to inner join a table with a temporary one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a rather complex query that I'm going to simplify it for making it easier to read:

```
SELECT `temp_table`.field1, `temp_table`.field2 FROM
(A TEMPORARY TABLE MADE OUT OF A SELECTION QUERY) AS temp_table
INNER JOIN table ON temp_table.field1 = table.id 
WHERE table.some_field = 'something'
```

I am currently using a RAW query for this, but now I want to rewrite it using either Query Builder or Eloquent ORM in Laravel. I am new to Laravel. So, any idea or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [fromSub](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_fromSub)

```
 DB::query()->fromSub(function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('your query to get the temp_table');
        }, 'temp_table')->join('table','table.id','=','temp_table.field1')
        ->where('table.some_field','something');
```

the method 'fromSub' take a string as second parameter, it is 'as' in sql, so you can use it to name the temp table  ....